# getting the gclid for all Google AdWords conversions for a given date range

Tags: google-ads

As I understand it, whenever someone clicks on a Google Ad a gclid parameter is added to the URL. My website logs this gclid parameter but I'd like to be able to compare my own websites logs to Google's list of gclid's for the same date range.

My question is: how do I get a list of gclid's that Google used for my website for a given date range?

Comment: No it's not possible to dowload gclids